# Change icons of specific cmd windows in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, icons

I typically have multiple cmd windows open for different purposes.  To keep them straight, I set the background colors, the titles, and the window icons.  I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and everything still works except for the customization of the icons.

I created shortcuts for the various cmd windows, and set custom icons in the shortcut.  In Windows 7, the cmd windows would inherit the icon of the shortcut used to launch it, but in Windows 10, cmd windows launched from a shortcut always show the *generic application icon* (not even the regular cmd icon).

Is there a way to get the old Windows 7 behavior in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should be retained from this answer and the comments below, is that
after my remark that there is no problem in setting the icons of
CMD shortcuts when using icons from `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll`,
the poster has moved his icons DLL to `C:\Windows\System32` and suddenly
it all started working well, exactly the same as it did before in Windows 7.

Apparently there is some new obscure restriction in Windows 10, surely in the
name of security, that for CMD windows only icon sources in
`C:\Windows\System32` are acceptable.

---

**Old answer** (relating to .bat files)

Windows 10 will not let one change the displayed icon for a `.bat` file that
is stored on the desktop. There is no explanation as to why this is so.

The solution is to store the file somewhere else, to create a desktop shortcut
to it and then to change the icon on that shortcut.

There is another weird problem in that the changed icon is not immediately
displayed, which gives the impression that the change did not work.
To fix this, type <kbd>F5</kbd> while the focus is on the desktop,
and this will refresh the desktop display.

In case when the icon display is totally broken, you could try to
[Rebuild a Broken Icon Cache](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/)
after setting your icons, then reboot.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the icons for batch files.  This question has nothing to do with batch files.  I created shortcuts to cmd.exe and I set the icons of the shortcuts.  The shortcuts display with the correct icons.  But when I launch a CMD window from one of those shortcuts, I get the generic icon on the CMD window (not even the CMD icon, but the generic Windows application icon).  Rebuilding the icon cache made no difference.

Comment: I have no problem changing the icon of a desktop shortcut to `cmd.exe` - it only needs F5 to display. Did you maybe  mean the icon that is on the title-bar of the cmd windows or the one on the taskbar? If you did, then the only solution is to make multiple copies of `cmd.exe` and hack their icons using a utility such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the CMD window inheriting the icon of the shortcut.  It works on Windows 7 without hacking cmd.exe.  It stopped working when I upgraded to Windows 10.  The fact that the CMD windows are showing the generic application icon rather than the CMD icon suggests that cmd.exe is trying to change its own icon but somehow failing.

Comment: I must say that I cannot duplicate your problem. I have created two direct desktop shortcuts to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`. Both accept very well a change in icons, and both display them when executed. See it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZphx.jpg).

Comment: I have used icons from `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` - try to see if they work for you. I'm starting to think that the icons you are using maybe are not of the right resolution.

Comment: The ones in shell32.dll work for me, but the icons I'm trying to use are provided in the same formats and sizes (per the resource viewer in Visual Studio).  On a lark, I moved the DLL I have the icons in from C:\util to C:\Windows\System32, and (voila!) it works now.  I didn't even need to refresh the cache.

Comment: +1 because the comment thread led me to the second part of the solution: putting the resource DLL in `C:\Windows\System32`.  Scott Schreiner's ideal to build a resource DLL (rather than referencing .ICOs directly) was also necessary.

Comment: I have added our latest exchange to my answer.

Comment: Since I had to combine both your answer and Scott's, the fairest thing I can thing to do is mark yours as the answer and award the bounty to Scott.

Answer (score 4):

This **should** be the default behavior. But I'm running into this exact issue with my new laptop (2017 Razer Blade). However, my desktop behaves as you would expect: icons set in the shortcut are reflected in the PowerShell window.

I first noticed this when my Ubuntu (Windows Linux Subsystem) window didn't have the Ubuntu icon on my laptop while it did on my desktop.

[image]

[image]

After some experimenting, I've discovered that:

1. This applies to CMD shortcuts as well.
2. Icons embedded in .exes and .dll work fine. It's just .ico files that don't work for some reason.
3. It doesn't appear to be account dependent. I made a new local account on the laptop and ran into the same issue.

Sorry that this isn't an exact answer, but maybe it will help lead to a comprehensive solution.

Comment: I put the icons into a DLL and re-made the shortcuts to refer to the icons inside the DLL, but that made no difference.  I think this is just a Windows 10 bug.

Comment: Drat. Sorry to hear that. Sounds like the root cause of our issues might be different then. I did manage to inadvertently resolve my issue today after changing my screen scaling under Display Settings from a custom percentage to 100%. I have no idea why it started to work after this, but there you have it.

Comment: +1 because putting them in a DLL was a necessary step, but not sufficient.  I also had to put that DLL in `C:\Windows\system32`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different icon file type, such as .ico, .icl, .exe, .dll. Also, make sure the file(.ico) is not beyond the maximum size of 256x256 pixels.

**Icons**:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742485.aspx#size_requirements

Besides, make sure system is fully patched with Windows Update/Hotfix.

Comment: The icons are in .ico files and have the usual variety of sizes from 32x32 to 128x128 as 32-bit bitmaps plus a 256x256 as a 32-bit PNG.  Nothing larger.  One of them also as a 16x16 version.  Visual Studio seems to think they're well-formed.  The icons work fine on the shortcuts whether they're on the desktop or the quick launch toolbar, it's just the CMD window that won't show them.  I'm all patched and up-to-date.